# Keeping a fixed positioned div within the viewport - content scrollable?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position, viewport-units

I have a div that displays content once a product is added to a shopping basket. Basically once someone adds something to cart a popup appears in the top right of the screen pointing at the basket icon. This works ok but I'm concerned about what happens if a customer adds a lot of products to the basket - obviously it's going to run off the bottom of the page and that'll mean some of the content + the checkout button will be out of view.

Here's my working example: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/eVXBvP

I'm happy for just about any solution for this. I thought it would be nice if the footer with price + button always remained in view so only the product area was scrollable but maybe that's not possible?

I guess one of the problems with this is the `top` value, which means it's difficult (impossible?) to use a `max-height: 100%` on the `.mini-cart` container?

Also when scaling the browser horizontally the left edge of the box runs off the screen when it gets really narrow - how can I avoid this? I've resolved a similar issue before by using:

```
position: fixed;
top: 100px;
right: 30px;
left: 30px;
width: auto;
max-width: 500px;
```

But the problem with that is the div aligns to the left of the page by default and I need to left aligned. Is that possible?

I've tried the `vh` values but again I think the `top: 100px` value causes problems with that.

Comment: Next time please provide code directly inside Stackoverflow, as your Codepen could change and future visitors of this thread won't see the original issue.

Comment: My CodePen's code shouldn't change if I fork it though - isn't that right? Sorry if I'm wrong. I was just thinking it contains an absolute wall of CSS and posting that could be counter productive but I will post it all in future if that's what's required! :)

Comment: It's okay! Not everyone forks so one can never be too sure. Your code has SCSS which Stackoverflow snippets don't support (yet?), so you can post both in certain cases.

Comment: Yeah and I suppose it's easy to save/overwrite a CodePen by accident! Makes sense, I'll make sure to do that in future and if I use SCSS to post the compiled CSS here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the cart from going off the left side of the screen on resize, consider changing `width` to `500px` and `max-width` to no more than `100%`, I suggest `max-width: calc(100% - 40px);` as you got the cart at a `right` of 30px;

```
.mini-cart {
    background: white;
    border-top: 4px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    right: 30px;
    transition: all .20s;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 500px;
    max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

To help with scrolling for more items. You can let the entire cart scroll in place, or just let the items `mini-cart__body` scroll with setting a fixed `max-height` and set `overflow` to auto. NB: I set the `max-height` to `30vh` (vertical height of screen); for demonstration. something like `80vh` will make more sense for the live site.

```
.mini-cart__body {
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-right: 30px;
    margin-right: -30px;
    max-height: 30vh;
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
```

** UPDATE: based on the author's comments, it would be a good idea to handle for screens with a smaller height.

For this, just an idea here as there are many options... change the cart's `position` from being `fixed` to `absolute`

like:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 500px) {
  .mini-cart {
    position:absolute;
  }
  .mini-cart__body {
    max-height: inherit;
  }
}
```

** Here's the entire snippet (with the SCSS compiled to CSS to work here)

NB: some of the styles might have gotten changed in the css conversion. so, just use the following as an example.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var mn = $('.page-head'),
  core = $('.band'),
  mns = 'page-head-scrolled',
  bit, hdr;

  $(window).resize(function() {

    bit = mn.outerHeight();
    hdr = $('.info-bar').outerHeight();
  })
  .resize().scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > hdr) {
      mn.addClass(mns);
      core.css('margin-top', bit);
    } else {
      mn.removeClass(mns);
      core.attr('style', '');
    }
  })
  .on('load', function() {

    $(this).scroll();
  });
});
```

```css
/* =================
   #MIXINS
   ================= */
/**
 * Clearfix
 */
/**
 * Typography
 */
/**
 * Media Queries.
 * 
 * 1. $bp2  =  480px  (30rem)
 * 2. $bp3  =  600px  (37.5rem)
 * 3. $bp4  =  768px  (48rem)
 * 4. $bp5  =  1024px  (64rem)
 * 5. $bp6  =  1220px  (76.250rem)
 * 6. $bp7  =  1400px  (87.5rem)
 */
/* =================
   #BASE
   ================= */
/* Site */
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Page */
.page {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

/* Content area */
.band {
  padding: 60px 0 30px;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

/* =================
   #HEADER
   ================= */
/* Info bar */
.info-bar {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Header */
.page-head {
  background: #eee;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.page-head.page-head-scrolled {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

/* =================
   #MINI CART
   ================= */
.mini-cart {
  background: white;
  border-top: 4px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all .20s;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  /* [1] */
  /* [2] */
  /* [3] */
  /* [4] */
  /* [5] */
  /* [6] */
}
.mini-cart:before, .mini-cart:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.mini-cart:after {
  clear: both;
}
.mini-cart:before {
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid red;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .mini-cart {
    padding: 30px;
  }
}

/**
 * `mini-cart` header (title + close).
 */
.mini-cart__head {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.mini-cart__head:before, .mini-cart__head:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.mini-cart__head:after {
  clear: both;
}

.mini-cart__title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mini-cart__close {
  background: none;
  fill: #ccc;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  text-shadow: none;
  width: 20px;
}
.mini-cart__close:hover {
  fill: #333;
}

/**
 * `mini-cart` body (products).
 */
.mini-cart__body {
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-right: 30px;
    margin-right: -30px;
    max-height: 30vh;
    overflow: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}

.mini-cart__item {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  clear: both;
  padding: 30px 120px 30px 115px;
  position: relative;
}
.mini-cart__item:before, .mini-cart__item:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.mini-cart__item:after {
  clear: both;
}
.mini-cart__item .u-photo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -115px;
  width: 100px;
}
.mini-cart__item .p-name {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.mini-cart__item .e-description {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.mini-cart__item .p-price {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.mini-cart__item .qty {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

/**
 * `mini-cart` foot (price + button).
 */
/* =================
   #MIXINS
   ================= */
/**
 * Clearfix
 */
/**
 * Typography
 */
/**
 * Media Queries.
 * 
 * 1. $bp2  =  480px  (30rem)
 * 2. $bp3  =  600px  (37.5rem)
 * 3. $bp4  =  768px  (48rem)
 * 4. $bp5  =  1024px  (64rem)
 * 5. $bp6  =  1220px  (76.250rem)
 * 6. $bp7  =  1400px  (87.5rem)
 */
/* =================
   #BASE
   ================= */
/* Site */
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Page */
.page {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

/* Content area */
.band {
  padding: 60px 0 30px;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

/* =================
   #HEADER
   ================= */
/* Info bar */
.info-bar {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Header */
.page-head {
  background: #eee;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.page-head.page-head-scrolled {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

/* =================
   #MINI CART
   ================= */
.mini-cart {
  background: white;
  border-top: 4px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all .20s;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  /* [1] */
  /* [2] */
  /* [3] */
  /* [4] */
  /* [5] */
  /* [6] */
}
.mini-cart:before, .mini-cart:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.mini-cart:after {
  clear: both;
}
.mini-cart:before {
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid red;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .mini-cart {
    padding: 30px;
  }
}

/**
 * `mini-cart` header (title + close).
 */
.mini-cart__head {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.mini-cart__head:before, .mini-cart__head:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.mini-cart__head:after {
  clear: both;
}

.mini-cart__title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mini-cart__close {
  background: none;
  fill: #ccc;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  text-shadow: none;
  width: 20px;
}
.mini-cart__close:hover {
  fill: #333;
}

/**
 * `mini-cart` body (products).
 */
.mini-cart__body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-right: 30px;
  margin-right: -30px;
}

.mini-cart__item {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  clear: both;
  padding: 30px 120px 30px 115px;
  position: relative;
}
.mini-cart__item:before, .mini-cart__item:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.mini-cart__item:after {
  clear: both;
}
.mini-cart__item .u-photo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -115px;
  width: 100px;
}
.mini-cart__item .p-name {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.mini-cart__item .e-description {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.mini-cart__item .p-price {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.mini-cart__item .qty {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

/**
 * `mini-cart` foot (price + button).
 */
.mini-cart {
    background: white;
    border-top: 4px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    right: 30px;
    transition: all .20s;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 500px;
    max-width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
.mini-cart__total:before, .mini-cart__total:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.mini-cart__total:after {
  clear: both;
}
.mini-cart__total span {
  float: right;
}

.mini-cart__btn {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mini-cart__total:before, .mini-cart__total:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.mini-cart__total:after {
  clear: both;
}
.mini-cart__total span {
  float: right;
}

.mini-cart__btn {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 350px) {

  .mini-cart {
    position:absolute;
  }
  .mini-cart__body {
    max-height: inherit;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">

  <div class="info-bar">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>

  <header class="page-head">
    <h3>Main Nav would go in here</h3>
  </header>

  <div class="band">
    <div class="wrap">

      <h4>All Page content follows</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <br />
        <br />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <br />
        <br />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <br />
        <br />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <br />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Start #mini-cart -->
<div class="mini-cart">

  <div class="mini-cart__head">
    <a href="#" class="mini-cart__close">Close</a>
    <h4 class="mini-cart__title">Your Basket</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="mini-cart__body">

    <div class="mini-cart__item h-product">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      <h2 class="p-name">Product title</h2>
      <p class="e-description">Short product description</p>
      <p class="p-price">£99.99</p>
      <div class="qty qty--small">QTY</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mini-cart__item h-product">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      <h2 class="p-name">Product title</h2>
      <p class="e-description">Short product description</p>
      <p class="p-price">£99.99</p>
      <div class="qty qty--small">QTY</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="mini-cart__foot">
    <p class="mini-cart__total">Total <span>£11.00</span></p>
    <a href="#" class="mini-cart__btn btn btn--wide">Checkout</a>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- End #mini-cart -->
```

Comment: Thanks for that, worked a treat on the positional sense. On the scrollable content keeping the checkout button in view makes sense so scrollable `body` area would be best. However I've noticed on short browser windows that'll mean the button can break out of the box. Do you get that? Maybe it's because I've set `max-height: calc(100vh - 115px);` on the mini-cart container also?

Comment: Hey, that is a good point, to check the display on a shorter screens/browser windows. I'm thinking for situations like this, add a media screen catch for `max-height` and actually change the position from being fixed, to `absolute` as that might help with more natural scrolling. I updated my code example to reflect this. There are many options you can go with. Let me know if you'd like to try something different. (NB: I changed the page height to make this example more adaptive to the preview window here.)

Comment: That's a good solution! Though it might look a bit odd with the fixed position nav - which I could also change to absolute/relative. Part of me wonders how useful this is on mobile and if it's worth just hiding it. Alternatively I could set heights on the header/footer so the body and use calc ...getting a bit messy but could work!

Comment: Well, good luck. It's a nice cart design you got.  I'm not positive you'd consider whether my last updated answer can be marked as correct or not. Let me know if I could try modify it further.

Comment: Thanks a lot - a lot of stolen (refactored ;)) examples from sites I've seen rolled into one. Probably best when it's a single product. I imagine it'd be a nightmare on a site where someone would be adding lots and lots of items to! Thanks again for all your time and help :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `display: flex;`, `flex-direction: column;` and `max-height: calc(100vh - 100px);` on your `.mini-cart`, you can get the result you want: [See this JSFiddle for SCSS code in action](https://jsfiddle.net/zekj7e63/5/).

The flex makes sure the elements fit inside the container. To be extra safe you can add `flex` rules to is direct descendants. I am merely providing a general solution you can build upon to fit your exact needs.

I had to edit slightly your `.mini-cart__body`, adding a `@media` rule with your predefined breakpoint so the scrollbar wouldn't get outside the container.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var mn = $('.page-head'),
  core = $('.band'),
  mns = 'page-head-scrolled',
  bit, hdr;

  $(window).resize(function() {

    bit = mn.outerHeight();
    hdr = $('.info-bar').outerHeight();
  })
  .resize().scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > hdr) {
      mn.addClass(mns);
      core.css('margin-top', bit);
    } else {
      mn.removeClass(mns);
      core.attr('style', '');
    }
  })
  .on('load', function() {

    $(this).scroll();
  });
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

/* =================
   #MIXINS
   ================= */

/**
 * Clearfix
 */

@mixin clearfix() {
 
 &:before,
 &:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
 }
 
 &:after {
  clear: both;
 }
}


/**
 * Typography
 */

@mixin font-size($font-size: 16){
font-size : #{$font-size}px;
font-size : #{$font-size / 10}rem; }


/**
 * Media Queries.
 * 
 * 1. $bp2  =  480px  (30rem)
 * 2. $bp3  =  600px  (37.5rem)
 * 3. $bp4  =  768px  (48rem)
 * 4. $bp5  =  1024px  (64rem)
 * 5. $bp6  =  1220px  (76.250rem)
 * 6. $bp7  =  1400px  (87.5rem)
 */

@mixin bp($point) {
  
  $bp2 : "(min-width : 30em)";   /* [1] */
  $bp3 : "(min-width : 37.5em)";   /* [2] */
  $bp4 : "(min-width : 48em)";   /* [3] */
  $bp5 : "(min-width : 64em)";   /* [4] */
  $bp6 : "(min-width : 76.250em)";  /* [5] */
  $bp7 : "(min-width : 87.5em)";   /* [6] */

  @if $point == bp2 {
    @media #{$bp2} { @content; }
  }

  @else if $point == bp3 {
    @media #{$bp3} { @content; }
  }

  @else if $point == bp3 {
    @media #{$bp3} { @content; }
  }

  @else if $point == bp4 {
    @media #{$bp4} { @content; }
  }

  @else if $point == bp5 {
    @media #{$bp5} { @content; }
  }

  @else if $point == bp6 {
    @media #{$bp6} { @content; }
  }

  @else if $point == bp7 {
    @media #{$bp7} { @content; }
  }
}


/* =================
   #BASE
   ================= */

/* Site */

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Page */

.page {
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

/* Content area */

.band {
  padding: 60px 0 30px;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}


/* =================
   #HEADER
   ================= */

/* Info bar */

.info-bar {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Header */

.page-head {
  background: #eee;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  
  &.page-head-scrolled {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
}


/* =================
   #MINI CART
   ================= */

.mini-cart {
 background: white;
 border-top: 4px solid red;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 @include clearfix;
 padding: 15px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 60px;
 right: 30px;
 transition: all .20s;
 z-index: 1000;
 max-width: 500px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

    &:before {
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 8px solid red;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 0; 
        position: absolute;
        top: -12px;
        right: 30px;
        width: 0; 
    }
    
    @include bp(bp5) {
     padding: 30px;
    }
}


/**
 * `mini-cart` header (title + close).
 */
 
.mini-cart__head {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
 @include clearfix;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.mini-cart__title {
 @include font-size(18);
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mini-cart__close {
   background: none;
   fill: #ccc;
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    text-shadow: none;
    width: 20px;
    
    &:hover {
        fill: #333;
    }
}


/**
 * `mini-cart` body (products).
 */

.mini-cart__body {
 overflow-y: auto;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-right:  0;
  
  @include bp(bp5) {
   padding-right: 30px;
   margin-right: -30px;
  }
}

.mini-cart__item {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
    clear: both;
    @include clearfix;
    padding: 30px 120px 30px 115px;
    position: relative;
    
    .u-photo {
     display: block;
     float: left;
     margin-left: -115px;
     width: 100px;
    }
    
    .p-name {
     @include font-size(14);
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    .e-description {
     @include font-size(12);
     margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    .p-price {
     margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .qty {
     position: absolute;
     top: 30px;
     right: 0;
     text-align: right;
    }
}

/**
 * `mini-cart` foot (price + button).
 */

.mini-cart__total {
    @include clearfix;
    color: #333;
    @include font-size(18);
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 15px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
    
    span {
     float: right;
    }
}

.mini-cart__btn {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">

  <div class="info-bar">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>

  <header class="page-head">
    <h3>Main Nav would go in here</h3>
  </header>

  <div class="band">
    <div class="wrap">

      <h4>All Page content follows</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Start #mini-cart -->
<div class="mini-cart">

  <div class="mini-cart__head">
    <a href="#" class="mini-cart__close">Close</a>
    <h4 class="mini-cart__title">Your Basket</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="mini-cart__body">

    <div class="mini-cart__item h-product">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      <h2 class="p-name">Product title</h2>
      <p class="e-description">Short product description</p>
      <p class="p-price">£99.99</p>
      <div class="qty qty--small">QTY</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mini-cart__item h-product">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      <h2 class="p-name">Product title</h2>
      <p class="e-description">Short product description</p>
      <p class="p-price">£99.99</p>
      <div class="qty qty--small">QTY</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mini-cart__item h-product">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      <h2 class="p-name">Product title</h2>
      <p class="e-description">Short product description</p>
      <p class="p-price">£99.99</p>
      <div class="qty qty--small">QTY</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mini-cart__item h-product">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      <h2 class="p-name">Product title</h2>
      <p class="e-description">Short product description</p>
      <p class="p-price">£99.99</p>
      <div class="qty qty--small">QTY</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="mini-cart__foot">
    <p class="mini-cart__total">Total <span>£11.00</span></p>
    <a href="#" class="mini-cart__btn btn btn--wide">Checkout</a>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- End #mini-cart -->
```

(note: this is based on the SCSS the OP provided so the snippet will no render properly, see the JSFiddle at the start of my answer)

Comment: This looks good! I'll test it out on my build in the morning, thanks. What's the browser support like for this, IE10? That's fine. I can just hide the mini-cart on IE9 (if I need to support it)!

Comment: Support for these properties is good in IE10 (`-ms-` prefixes and older spec names might be needed).

Comment: I think it would be fine to hide the cart if the browser doesn't support the properties but it doesn't sound like that'll be an issue. Providing the link then went to the basket/checkout when clicked. When you say _"To be extra safe you can add flex rules to is direct descendants."_ is that so the child elements aren't affected/resized using flex?

Comment: @user1406440 You can add `flex: 1 0 auto` on the list, and `flex: 0 0 none` on the top and bottom elements to ensure they don't take more space when the list is small. It can also be useful to normalise cross-browser behaviour. That's all, but globally it should work fine as it is.

Comment: Cool, I didn't see that causing a problem actually. It seems to work ok how it is. The only thing I noticed was when I reduced the size of my browser window down to mobile size the image shrunk in size but it has a fixed width of 100px. Is there a way to stop that?

Comment: That's up to you to set in your CSS ruleset for `.mini-cart__item .u-photo` (which you could make a lot better with flex, rather than float and negative margins). That is not related to the original question for which I provided an answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set **[`overflow: scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)** in addition to **[`max-height: 100%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height)** on `.mini-cart`.

This can be seen [**here**](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/JpzEjG), and also in the following:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var mn = $('.page-head'),
    core = $('.band'),
    mns = 'page-head-scrolled',
    bit, hdr;

  $(window).resize(function() {

      bit = mn.outerHeight();
      hdr = $('.info-bar').outerHeight();
    })
    .resize().scroll(function() {

      if ($(this).scrollTop() > hdr) {
        mn.addClass(mns);
        core.css('margin-top', bit);
      } else {
        mn.removeClass(mns);
        core.attr('style', '');
      }
    })
    .on('load', function() {

      $(this).scroll();
    });
});
```

```css
/* =================
   #MIXINS
   ================= */


/**
 * Clearfix
 */


/**
 * Typography
 */


/**
 * Media Queries.
 * 
 * 1. $bp2  =  480px  (30rem)
 * 2. $bp3  =  600px  (37.5rem)
 * 3. $bp4  =  768px  (48rem)
 * 4. $bp5  =  1024px  (64rem)
 * 5. $bp6  =  1220px  (76.250rem)
 * 6. $bp7  =  1400px  (87.5rem)
 */


/* =================
   #BASE
   ================= */


/* Site */

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Page */

.page {
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}


/* Content area */

.band {
  padding: 60px 0 30px;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}


/* =================
   #HEADER
   ================= */


/* Info bar */

.info-bar {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Header */

.page-head {
  background: #eee;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.page-head.page-head-scrolled {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}


/* =================
   #MINI CART
   ================= */

.mini-cart {
  background: white;
  border-top: 4px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all .20s;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  /* [1] */
  /* [2] */
  /* [3] */
  /* [4] */
  /* [5] */
  /* [6] */
}

.mini-cart:before,
.mini-cart:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.mini-cart:after {
  clear: both;
}

.mini-cart:before {
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid red;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .mini-cart {
    padding: 30px;
  }
}


/**
 * `mini-cart` header (title + close).
 */

.mini-cart__head {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.mini-cart__head:before,
.mini-cart__head:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.mini-cart__head:after {
  clear: both;
}

.mini-cart__title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mini-cart__close {
  background: none;
  fill: #ccc;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  text-shadow: none;
  width: 20px;
}

.mini-cart__close:hover {
  fill: #333;
}


/**
 * `mini-cart` body (products).
 */

.mini-cart__body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-right: 30px;
  margin-right: -30px;
}

.mini-cart__item {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  clear: both;
  padding: 30px 120px 30px 115px;
  position: relative;
}

.mini-cart__item:before,
.mini-cart__item:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.mini-cart__item:after {
  clear: both;
}

.mini-cart__item .u-photo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -115px;
  width: 100px;
}

.mini-cart__item .p-name {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.mini-cart__item .e-description {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.mini-cart__item .p-price {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.mini-cart__item .qty {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 0;
  text-align: right;
}


/**
 * `mini-cart` foot (price + button).
 */

.mini-cart__total {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}

.mini-cart__total:before,
.mini-cart__total:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.mini-cart__total:after {
  clear: both;
}

.mini-cart__total span {
  float: right;
}

.mini-cart__btn {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="page">

  <div class="info-bar">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  </div>

  <header class="page-head">
    <h3>Main Nav would go in here</h3>
  </header>

  <div class="band">
    <div class="wrap">

      <h4>All Page content follows</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Start #mini-cart -->
<div class="mini-cart">

  <div class="mini-cart__head">
    <a href="#" class="mini-cart__close">Close</a>
    <h4 class="mini-cart__title">Your Basket</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="mini-cart__body">

    <div class="mini-cart__item h-product">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      <h2 class="p-name">Product title</h2>
      <p class="e-description">Short product description</p>
      <p class="p-price">£99.99</p>
      <div class="qty qty--small">QTY</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mini-cart__item h-product">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      <h2 class="p-name">Product title</h2>
      <p class="e-description">Short product description</p>
      <p class="p-price">£99.99</p>
      <div class="qty qty--small">QTY</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mini-cart__item h-product">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      <h2 class="p-name">Product title</h2>
      <p class="e-description">Short product description</p>
      <p class="p-price">£99.99</p>
      <div class="qty qty--small">QTY</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mini-cart__item h-product">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      <h2 class="p-name">Product title</h2>
      <p class="e-description">Short product description</p>
      <p class="p-price">£99.99</p>
      <div class="qty qty--small">QTY</div>
    </div>

    <div class="mini-cart__item h-product">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="u-photo" alt="ALT TEXT" />
      <h2 class="p-name">Product title</h2>
      <p class="e-description">Short product description</p>
      <p class="p-price">£99.99</p>
      <div class="qty qty--small">QTY</div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="mini-cart__foot">
    <p class="mini-cart__total">Total <span>£11.00</span></p>
    <a href="#" class="mini-cart__btn btn btn--wide">Checkout</a>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- End #mini-cart -->
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that'll work due to the top value set on the `position: fixed` element. So it would run off the bottom of the page at 100% height.